# tchar.h not found on cygwin

Tags: c++, windows-7, cross-platform, cygwin, tchar

I'm running the latest cygwin on windows 7 (32-bit), and trying to build an open-source project, [RtAudio](http://www.music.mcgill.ca/~gary/rtaudio/) (it doesn't currently build on this platform).

One of the problems I've worked around is an error on the line
`#include <tchar.h>`.

My build line is:

```
g++ -O2 -Wall -Iinclude -DHAVE_GETTIMEOFDAY -D__WINDOWS_DS__ -c RtAudio.cpp -o RtAudio.o
```

The error is:

```
tchar.h: No such file or directory
```

If I add /usr/include/mingw (which contains tchar.h) to the list of include paths, I get a lot more errors.

I've worked around the problem by not using LPCTSTR, and just overloading the one function that requires it for `const char*` and `const wchar_t*` so I could avoid including tchar.h, but is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Why are you using Cygwin?  RtAudio claims to have native Windows support; you'd be better off using MinGW directly, or a Microsoft compiler.  It looks like the RtAudio distribution includes a Visual Studio setup that may be informative.

Comment: @Porculus, good question. Other components that I'm using require a linuxy environment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`tchar.h` is a Windows header. The software will have to be ported to libiconv or ICU if it needs more than just the basics.

Comment: so it sounds like the overload is the way to go in this situation?

Comment: I can't really say without knowing exactly what you did.

Comment: tchar.h cannot be found

Comment: are you saying that gcc does not have tchar.h ?

Comment: @MistyD: GCC will never have `tchar.h`.

Comment: thanks that worked, for followers, for me seemed to be `#include "w32api/windows.h"` (in cygwin) or you can include the tchar.h file directly

Answer (score 2):

If you want to build this for Cygwin, you should ensure that it uses the Unix/Linux code paths rather than the Windows ones. In particular, the **WIN32** macro is often used to guard Windows code, but that's defined on Cygwin too, so you might have to change any such guards to `#if defined(__WIN32__) && !defined(__CYGWIN__)`.

The other way of course is to build this for native Windows. Within Cygwin, you can do this using `gcc-3 -mno-cygwin` or the MinGW-w64 cross compiler that was recently added to the Cygwin distro.

Comment: could you explain what you mean by `#if defined(__WIN32__) && !defined(__CYGWIN__).` where should i add that header ?