# _T not recognized - porting tchar.h from microsoft to gcc

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, gcc

I am trying to port a component that runs fine on Microsoft Visual studio
The component has the following code in it

```
if ( SuperNode.someMethod == _T( "Hello" ) )
```

When attempting to build the code in gcc cygwin I get the following error

```
error: '_T' was not declared in this scope|
```

Now in visual studio `_T` points to `tchar.h`
Which has something like this

```
#define _T(x)       __T(x)
#define _TEXT(x)    __T(x)
```

What could I do to fix this problem for gcc cygwin ? Ill be running it on windows

Comment: Are you porting to GCC *for Windows*, or are you porting to some other operating system? If the latter, please say which.  What you should do is *completely different* depending on the answer to this question.

Comment: ill be running it on windows. The code is written on windows visual studio and I ma porting it to gcc cygwin which will also be run on windows

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As discussed for instance at [tchar.h not found on cygwin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4168748/tchar-h-not-found-on-cygwin) , Cygwin (being a compatibility layer which attempts to emulate the POSIX programming interface on top of Windows) has more in common with a Unix implementation than it does Windows.  In particular, it does not provide `tchar.h`.

What you should do about this depends on your larger goals: *why* are you trying to compile this program using something other than Visual Studio?  Here are some possibilities:

- You want a more standard-conforming C++ implementation than VS2010 provides, but you still want to build a native Windows application.  The path of least resistance is probably to switch to a newer version of Visual Studio instead; the "Express" editions of these are free-as-in-beer.  You could also try [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/), which is a GCC backend that produces *native* Windows applications, and [Clang for Windows](http://blog.llvm.org/2014/07/clangllvm-on-windows-update.html).
- You need to interoperate at the ABI level with (e.g. load DLLs into) a C++ program that was compiled using MinGW.  In that case you should also be using MinGW.  (Clang-for-Windows is supposed to be ABI-compatible with Visual Studio, so it won't work in this case.  Note that if the ABI involved is specified *entirely in plain C*, then there should be no problem loading a Visual Studio-compiled DLL into a MinGW-compiled program or vice versa.)
- This is stage one of a port to Unix (note: for purpose of this discussion, MacOS X counts as Unix), or you need to interoperate at the ABI level with a *Cygwin* program ... which means you have to port to Unix.  In that case, stage *zero* needs to be *stop using `tchar.h`*.

  What I mean by that is, go back to your Visual Studio builds, and then find every place in your code that uses anything defined in `tchar.h` (`_TCHAR`, `_T`, `_TEXT`, `_tcs*`, probably others) and change them to use either plain `char`, or `wchar_t`, as appropriate, and the associated string-literal syntax and functions.  You should also wean yourself off the generic (neither `A` nor `W` suffix) variant of the core Windows API at the same time.  I believe there is a macro you can define that causes `windows.h` not to provide the generic API at all, but I don't remember what it is and can't find it on MSDN right now.

  Keep in mind while doing this that Unix prefers you to use UTF-8-coded text in `char`/`std::string`, rather than UTF-16 text in `wchar_t`/`std::wstring` etc.  It has been my experience that a cross-platform application is generally happiest conforming to the Unix convention *except* in the functions that talk directly to the Windows API, which use exclusively the `W` variants of that API, converting back and forth right then and there.  (And you need to create yourself a compatibility layer and isolate all of that code there and arrange to have as little of it as possible.)

Answer (score 4):

In the Visual Studio headers, `_T` is defined to be `L` if compiling with wide character support, or nothing otherwise.

So if wide character support is enabled, `_T("blah blah blah")` will get preprocessed to `L"blah blah blah"`.

If wide character support is disabled, `_T("blah blah blah")` will get preprocessed to `"blah blah blah"`.

Comment: Except the question itself shows that `_T`'s definition is not _quite_ that simple :P

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I'll bet a cookie that that's just the double expansion hack, and `__T(x)` expands to either `L##x` or just `x` depending on a build parameter (probably `-DUNICODE` or not).

Comment: @zwol: Yes, I agree. Well done. That's still more complicated than this answer makes out.